# How to get single-spaced list environments in a double-spaced document

Tags: lists, line-spacing, enumitem

I am writing a double-spaced document based on the book class. I set the spacing using `\linespread{1.6}`.

Is there a way to get all `enumerate`, `itemize`, and `description` environments to be single-spaced rather than the default double-spaced? I do not mean the spacing between the items, but rather the spacing between the lines of a given item.

I would prefer a method that doesn't require me to define my own environment; I want to use the already existing `enumerate` etc.

I expected there to be a way in the `enumitem` package to do it, but I don't see any information about line spacing in the documentation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use

```
\setlist{before=\singlespacing,after=\doublespacing}
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setlist{before=\singlespacing,after=\doublespacing}
\doublespacing
\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1]
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item \lipsum[1]
    \item \lipsum[1]
  \end{enumerate}
  \lipsum[1]
  \begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[1]
    \item \lipsum[1]
  \end{itemize}
  \lipsum[1]
  \begin{description}
    \item[Some] \lipsum[1]
    \item[Other] \lipsum[1]
  \end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to use `\linespread` instead of `setspace macros, do this

```
\setlist{before=\linespread{1}\selectfont,after=\linespread{1.6}\selectfont}
```

Comment: Thank you. I verify this works with your MWE. I am now having some other issues with random changes from single to double spacing throughout the document and within lists, but I suspect this is some other package conflict I have going on.

Comment: You can also specify which type of list you want to change the spacing for, in case you don't want it to be global for all list environments.  In this case, add `\setlist[itemize]{before=\singlespacing,after=\doublespacing}` or `\setlist[enumerate]{before=\singlespacing,after=\doublespacing}`.  This is something I needed to do, and this question helped me figure out how to specify spacing in different list environments.